# How can objects be reordered using django-sortedm2m?

Tags: django, m2m

A `Collection` object can contain several `Item` objects, and an `Item` object can be contained by several `Collection` objects. The items should be ordered in each collection. I am using `django-sortedm2m`:

```py
from sortedm2m.fields import SortedManyToManyField

class Item(models.Model):
    pass

class Collection(models.Model):
    items = SortedManyToManyField(to=Item)
```

```py
>>> item_1 = Item.objects.create()
>>> item_2 = Item.objects.create()
>>> collection = Collection.objects.create()
>>> collection.items.set([item_2, item_1])
>>> collection.items.all()
<QuerySet [<Item 2>, <Item 1>]>
```

As expected, the order of items as they have been added is preserved. However, I want to reorder these elements, in the spirit of a "classic" model with `ForeignKeyField` and `order_with_respect_to`: `collection.set_item_order([1, 2])`. What is the best or simplest way to do that?

Comment: have you found a solution for this, please?

Comment: I'm afraid not. To this day this remains a # TODO in my project.

Comment: if I find a solution, I'll let you know.